# try to understanding spark streaming jobs

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Trying to figure out how to write a streaming job relies on some 3rd party modules and look-up table to work, as follows:

```
# custom.py
# this is the 3rd party or user defined python module,
# there're some module-level variables
# and some functions which rely on the moduel-level variables to work
VAR_A = ...
VAR_B = ...


# load external data files to initialize VAR_A and VAR_B
def init_var(external_file):
  with open(external_file, 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
      VAR_A.append(l)
      VAR_B.check(l)
      ....

# relies on VAR_A and VAR_B to work
def process(x):
  if x in VAR_A:
    ...
  if VAR_B.check(x):
    ...
```

The streaming driver as follows, and basically, for each rdd I want to apply `custom`'s `process` function via `handle`, however in the `process` function relies on some look-up variables to work, i.e. `VAR_A` and `VAR_B`, so do I have to explicitly broadcast these look-up vars in Spark contenxt?

```
# driver.py
import custom

def handle(x):
  ...
  custom = shared.value
  return custom.process(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  sc = SparkContext(appName='porn_score_on_name')
  ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

  custom.init('/path/to/external_file')

  # since each task node will use custom, so I try to make it a shared one
  # HOWEVER, this won't work, since module cannot be pickled
  shared = sc.broadcast(custom)

  # get stream data
  data = ...
  processed = data.map(handle)

  # further processing
  ...

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I wonder how to make it work, if I have to use the 3rd party module?

**UPDATE**

Suppose the real-time streaming input with lines of words, e.g.

```
word1 word2
word3
word5 word7 word1
...
```

and I want to find out the lines with words in a precomputed vocabulary (V).

So I have this idea:
write a streaming job to process the incoming data, and that means I have multiple executor running in parallel to consume the data, and for each executor, the precomputed vocabular V should be available all the time.
Now the problem is how do I make it happen?

Here is my intial take at this:
I make a zip package containing the vocabulary and my custom code, e.g. pack.zip, and then I submit this pack.zip via `spark-submit`, so that this pack.zip is available on each executor machine, then I should do something to make each executor load the vocabulary from pack.zip into a in-memory look-up table, so that now each executor has access to the vocabulary, so they could correctly handle the real-time streaming data when the driver starts running.

However it turns out that, the above idea could work, but each executor loads the vocabulary again and again per batch, that's not acceptable.
So here is my second take:
I should load the vocabulary in the driver (so this happens on the local machine right, not on the executors), and then I broadcast the vocabulary look-up table to all the executors, and then to do the job.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but yes, all variables and modules must be serializable to Spark (or pickled via Python)

Comment: @cricket_007, basically, I just wan to call `custom`'s `process` function inside `handle`.

Comment: @cricket_007, updated post with some details. BTW, if all needed modules must be serialized on Spark, then what's the point of uploading packages via `--py-files` or `--archives` etc?

Comment: AFAIK, `--py-files` must be directly accessible on all nodes of the cluster (assuming you use one). For example, if I have `numpy` on one machine, but not the others, the code will fail with "module not installed" on some other Spark executor

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, I know. So that each executor could run some operations which rely on `numpy`. Actually what I'm doing is pretty much the same as your `numpy` example, here in my case, I want each executor could user `custom`'s functions and variables like `process`, 'VAR_A`. At first I thought I could submit the data files and `custom.py` via --py-files to the cluster, then I command each executor to run `custom.init` function to load the data files, and then could `process` each rdd, however it doesn't seem to work at all, so I'm stuck here.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your examples with all the `...`'s. But, basically, my point is this: Your modules aren't going to "share state" amongst the Spark executors and separate threads. And whatever file you are opening is going to be opened with *each executor*.

Comment: @cricket_007, could you please share some similar code examples with me?

Comment: I have none. Please, show a [mcve] (keyword of complete) and maybe your question will become more clear.

Comment: @cricket_007, I updated the post, added a simple example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't really seem to be a streaming problem, but just how to load a global variable...

I wouldn't try to broadcast a whole module, just the variables that are required individually.

For example, you should be able to use a broadcast variable like so. (code untested)

```
# One of the first things you do
vocab = sc.broadcast(open('vocab.txt').readlines())  # broadcast to all executors

def vocab_filter(line):
    words = line.split()
    return [w for w in words if w in vocab.value]

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)  # Some streaming context
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)  # Some stream
# remove extraneous words from the lines and flatten all words in the stream
lines_filtered = lines.flatMap(vocab_filter)
```

Comment: Yes and thanks, I completely understand your code example here. However, the most annoying issue in my problem, is that I need to use a 3rd party module's look-up function, e.g. `process`, and this functions is written in an un-friendly fashion, like this `def process(line_of_string): for word in line_of_string.split(): yield word if word in GLOBAL_VOCAB`,  that is it assumes this is a module-level variable `GLOBAL_VOCAB` in this 3rd party module containing the vocabulary, so now even if I could do the `broadcast` like you did, then I could I make the call to 3rd party `process`?

Comment: `GLOBAL_VOCAB` itself must be the broadcast variable. Otherwise, I don't see why what you just mentioned wouldn't work

Comment: BTW, the vocab loading is not that simple as your code, besides reading them, a `trie` needs being built over those vocabulary words, so how to load the vocabulary file and build the `trie` just once on each executor, not rebuild the `trie` again and again (this is one issue in my code)

Comment: You build the trie, and you broadcast it... However, making a `class Trie` wouldn't be a bad idea, and you'd want to ensure that you can `pickle` that class.